# How can I reduce duplicate code in the sequalizer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize. The content is from 1 to 10, and the ingredients are also from 1 to 10.

For ingredients from 1 to 10, all 3 contents from 1 to 10 are searched. This makes the code too long. Is there any way to reduce the duplication of this code?

Ingredients from 1 to 10 should look up the 3 contents of 1 to 10 in all cases.

this is my code

```
     (post.js)

    module.exports = class Post extends Model {
      static init(sequelize) {
        return super.init(
          {
            name: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content1: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content2: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content3: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content4: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content5: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content6: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content7: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content8: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content9: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },
            content10: {
              type: DataTypes.TEXT,
              allowNull: false,
            },



example code (router.js) 

    router.post("/cookup/postss", async (req, res, next) => {

      try {
        const posts = await Post.findAll({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                [Op.and]: [
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content3: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },


              {
                [Op.and]: [
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content1: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content2: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content4: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            
              .
              .
              .
              .
              .
              .
              {
                [Op.and]: [
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content8: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content9: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    [Op.or]: [
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients1 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients2 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients3 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients4 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients5 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients6 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients7 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients8 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients9 },
                      { content10: req.body.ingredients10 },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ]
          },
          limit: 30,
          offset: hi,
          order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
          include: [
            {
              model: User,
              attributes: ["id", "nickname"],
            },
            {
              model: Image,
            },
            {
              model: User,
              as: "Likers",
              attributes: ["id"],
            },
          ],

        })
      }
```

Comment: Lokks like you need an additional table for storing content records. That way you can have them as many as you want and another benefit would be simplifying queries.